find 2 possible values for x in a non-right triangle
Show to possible answers for x
$5^2=x^2+6^2-2(x)(6)cos60$
This is a quadratic and can anyone help me with this question using the Cosine rule.

So basically you get the equation
$$
5^2 = x^2 + 6^2 - 2x\cdot 6 \cos 40^{\circ}
$$
What did you do next?

I do not know what to do next can some on help me?

Please don’t use
images instead of typing your formulas

Sorry I am kind of in a hurry

I just made my account because I have been stuck at this question for the past 1 hour

I need to earn 10 reputations so I can get more benefits so pls don't give me bad votting

Why don't you solve that quadratic equation?

I dunno how to pls help?

It looks like the diagram and the equation in your post do not match. Also, have you tried to do anything? You mention having been stuck for the past hour, which suggests that there are some things you've tried, but you haven't included any of your ideas or efforts.

You can search on the internet for "how to solve quadratic equations" you will find many texts and video tutorials. For example, see this or this one

Do you know the cosine of $60$ degrees? And could you please choose a nicer screen name?

Note that the angle opposite the side of length $5$ in the diagram at the link you give is $40^\circ$, not $\color{red}{60^\circ}$ as you've stated in your above description of the problem. There is no triangle with sides of lengths $5$ and $6$ and an angle of $60^\circ$ opposite the side of length $5$.

Your image is very bad, here's a better one:

You can see $|AB|$ being $6$.
Out of $B$, there's a line on an angle of $40°$.
Out of $A$, you draw a circle with radius $5$.
Question: how much intersection points are there between the circle with radius $5$ and the line at $40°$ from point $B$?

This is pretty good, but I also want to add an animated version similar to your diagram that can help @Turd visualize it better: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/aex7bwupno

On second glance however, I realized that the OP wants help with solving the given quadratic and using the Law of Sines/Cosines, not necessarily with understanding the problem itself.
